# How to get Payment method in razorpay response?

Tags: jquery, ajax, wordpress, razorpay

Am currently using Razorpay in my wordpress site. In that, I am getting **razorpay_payment_id** as a response on Successful transcations. but, I couldn't find the payment method(ex: wallet,netbanking) used by the end user!!
I want to capture the payment method used by the end user! How to acheive this??

Here is my code to make request and receive response from razorpay,

```
    var options={
        "key": "XXXXXXXXXX",
        "amount": $('input:radio[name="donate_amnt"]:checked').val()*100, 
        "name": $("#donor_fname").val(),
        "description": "Donation amount",
        "callback_url": 'XXXXXXXXXX',
        "handler": function (response){
            var razorpayid=response.razorpay_payment_id;
                    alert(razorpayid);                              

        },
        "prefill": {
            "contact": $("#donor_mobno").val(),
            "email": $("#donor_emailid").val()
        },
        "theme": {
            "color": "#b80105"
        },
 }
        var rzp1 = new Razorpay(options);
        rzp1.open();
```